# Camera intrinsic matrix for single photo capture on iOS

Tags: ios, camera-calibration, avcapturesession, avcapture

Is it possible to get the camera intrinsic matrix for a captured *single* photo on iOS?

I know that one can get the `cameraCalibrationData` from a `AVCapturePhoto`, which also contains the `intrinsicMatrix`. *However*, this is only provided when using a constituent (i.e. multi-camera) capture device and setting `virtualDeviceConstituentPhotoDeliveryEnabledDevices` to multiple devices (or enabling `isDualCameraDualPhotoDeliveryEnabled` on older iOS versions). Then `photoOutput(_:didFinishProcessingPhoto:)` is called multiple times, delivering one photo for each camera specified. Those then contain the calibration data.
As far as I know, there is no way to get the calibration data for a normal, single-camera photo capture.

I also found that one can set `isCameraIntrinsicMatrixDeliveryEnabled` on a capture connection that leads to a `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput`. The buffers that arrive at the delegate of that output then contain the intrinsic matrix via the `kCMSampleBufferAttachmentKey_CameraIntrinsicMatrix` metadata. *However*, this requires adding another output to the capture session, which feels quite wasteful just for getting this piece of metadata. Also, I would somehow need to figure out which buffer was temporarily closest to when the actual photo was taken.

Is there a better, simpler way for getting the camera intrinsic matrix for a single photo capture?

If not, is there a way to calculate the matrix based on the image's metadata?

Comment: got focal length and sensor pixel size?

Comment: The focal length I get from the metadata, but not the sensor size. I can, however, estimate it based on the `FocalLenIn35mmFilm` metadata, but that's a rather rough estimation as this value is rounded. It would be better to get the current values directly from the camera.